# X has no len when trying to make pagination in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build pagination in Django but it doesn't work - the numbers move yet the content does not change. How can I solve this problem?

File `models.py`

```
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)


class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, 
                  related_name='topics',on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, 
    related_name='topics',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_dt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

File `views.py`

```
def boards_topic(request, id):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=id)
    paginator = Paginator(board, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    # board = paginator.get_page(page)
    try:
        page_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page_list = paginator.page(Paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'board':board, }
    return render(request, 'topics.html',context)
```

File `url.py`

```
    path('boards/<int:id>/', views.boards_topic, name='boards_topic'),
```

With this, when trying out `/boards/1/`, I face the error

```py
TypeError at /boards/1/

object of type 'Board' has no len()

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/boards/1/?page=1
Django Version:     2.2.3
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

object of type 'Board' has no len()
```

---

Update//
The problem has been resolved.
Thanks to everyone who helped me.

views.py

```
def boards_topic(request, id):
board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=id)
board_list = board.topics.all()
paginator = Paginator(board_list, 3)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    board_list = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    board_list = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    board_list = paginator.page(Paginator.num_page)
context = {
    'board':board,
    'board_list': board_list,
    'page': page,

}

return render(request, 'topics.html',context)
```

Comment: `paginator = Paginator(board, 3)` Why are you doing pagination on a single `Board` object?  That makes no sense.  The entire point of pagination is that you have lots of objects to look at, but you're passing a single object to `Paginator()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I’m new to Dijango,
I did this too but it doesn't

    topics =Topic.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(topics, 3)

Comment: _I did this too but it doesn't_ It doesn't what?  If you meant to say "it doesn't work", please be specific.  **How** doesn't it work?  Do you get an error message?  Do you get no results at all?  Do you get different results than you expected?